# An unhandled exception has occurred: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'

Tags: c#, docker, exception, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using asp.net core 2.0 when i build to my web project for docker and run it as a container its throw an exception as below; but no any problem when i run it on local.

I did basically, before then docker build;

1. dotnet restore
2. dotnet build
3. dotnet publish

> **fail:**
>    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred: Cannot find compilation library location for package '**Microsoft.Win32.Registry**'
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library
>   location for package '**Microsoft.Win32.Registry**'

**This is my .csproj file** :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <!--<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>-->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Dockerfile">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  <Content Update="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="Embedded Resources">
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.component.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.component.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.component.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.module.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.module.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.module.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.routing.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.routing.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\app.routing.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Components\Home.component.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Components\Home.component.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Components\Home.component.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Components\inzmotivation.component.html" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Components\inzmotivation.component.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\system.config.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\main.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\main.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\main.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Model\InzMotivation.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\Service\inzmotivations.service.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\shared\enum.ts" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\shared\global.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\shared\global.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\shared\global.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="wwwroot\Components\inzmotivation.component.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="wwwroot\Model\InzMotivation.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="wwwroot\polyfills.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="wwwroot\Service\inzmotivations.service.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="k8config\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Startup.cs :**

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

           // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();                       
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:8181")
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();
}
```

Comment: This seems a regression: https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2377

Comment: @Gusman Thanks a lot. your url was very helpful. also i did update dotnet core cli to 2.2.0-preview1-007582 and it works fine!

Comment: @bilalkorkmaz, what should be done when .NET app is not created via CLI and it's deployed to the server?