# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'

Tags: c#, deployment, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC application that when deployed to server gives me this error:

Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'

And the more I try to solve it, the less I succeed.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417774/an-unhandled-exception-has-occurred-cannot-find-compilation-library-location-fo) a link to GitHub's repo is provided for `corefix` and when I go to installation page of `corefix` it redirects me back to **.NET Core 2.0.5** installation page alongside **SDK 2.1.4**. I have **[Windows Server Hosting Runtime 2.0.5](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)** installed on my server.

Also in that question it's been commented that updating CLI to 2.2.0 preview solves the problem, while I don't use CLI at all, so I still don't get it how to solve this error.

How do I solve this annoying error?

Also based on [this comment from GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981#issuecomment-354798881), I'm referencing version `2.0.3` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage, so the dependency model library should be the correct version.

The complete message of the error is:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile not available. Using 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\AutoGenKeys\S-1-5-82-1165741519-3190968648-2235264249-4167477242-938976022\DataProtection' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. Hosting environment: Production Content root path: C:\Jzp\PapillonWeb\Application\PublicPanel Now listening on: http://localhost:17215 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://papillon.phis.ir/   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method Jzp.PublicPanel.Controllers.DefaultController.Index (Jzp.PublicPanel) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Jzp.PublicPanel.Controllers.DefaultController.Index (Jzp.PublicPanel) in 665.9536ms fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry'    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List`1 assemblies)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences() at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences() at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Comment: could you please tell me what did you do to solve problem?

Comment: I published a project with `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` and then in `refs` folder I found this DLL. Then I put it in my source control.

Comment: where is `refs` folder after published in asp.net core 2 project? And how can i put dll in my source control?

Comment: It's just besides all files. It appears if you specify a runtime identifier.